# Get Alert if a schedule is created on ADF job

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Could you please let me know if there is a way to get an email alert if a schedule is created or a change is done to the existing schedule on Azure Data Factory Pipelines? This requirement is to monitor any schedule changes/ new schedule creations happening in the production environment and restrict them if done without proper approval in the project.

I tried using Azure log analytic workspace to achieve this requirement but the existing ADF log tables(ADFActivityRun, ADFPipelineRun, ADFTriggerRun) do not have any such information holding to write query (maybe am missing anything). Please let me know your views.

Many thanks in advance.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Roles and Permissions in ADF, you need `Contributor role` to create, edit, and delete data factories and child resources including datasets, linked services, pipelines, triggers, and integration runtimes.

**You can create custom rule for a group where users can only monitor a data factory (or factories) but can't modify it.**

You can refer this third-party tutorial on how to [Create Azure Custom Reader Role for Data Factory](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/role-reader/) and assign the role to a user whom you just want to give read permission.

For **alerts**, you can use Azure **Monitor** service to monitor and create alerts for your Azure Data Factory actions.

To get started, simply navigate to the `Monitor` tab in your data factory, select `Alerts & Metrics`, and then select `New Alert Rule`.

[image]

Give a name to your rule. Provide the `severity` to the alert. `Add criteria` to create a alert. There are plenty of scenarios available in the provided in-built criteria list. Then click on `Configure notification`.

[image]

The `Configure notification` allows you to choose options like Email, SMS, Azure notification and Voice call. You can choose multiple options as per your requirement.

[image]